# Remove columns from ResultSet by table

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbi

I'm using JDBI to query our DB. I have two tables that are connected via a foreign key and my query returns the join of both tables. To convert the returned values into objects I've implemented `ResultSetMapper` for my objects. The `ResultSet` from the query contains the columns of both tables: `t1.id, t1.name, t2.id, t2.name`. How can I split the according to the table name? I'm looking for this code:

```
public class T1Object {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private T2Object t2Object;
}

public class T2Object {
    private long id;
    private String name;
}

public void map(ResultSet r) {
    String t1Name = "Table1 name";
    String t2Name = "Table2 name";

    t1ResultSet = getResultSetByTableName(r, t1Name); // looking for this function's implementation
    t2ResultSet = getResultSetByTableName(r, t2Name);

    // convert each result set to an object using it's mapper...
}
```

The problem is that `Table1` and `Table2` have some columns with the same name so I've considered changing the query to return different names for each column and just parse the entire `ResultSet` but this won't scale well if I have lots of columns or I make changes only to `Table2` (I'll have to remember not only change the mapper for `Table2` but also go back to here and make changes).

I found this [solution](https://gist.github.com/DheerendraRathor/564a20a625b099abbe83) but it looks overly complex.

Any thoughts would be very appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

I suggest implementing your mappers with a column name prefix as an optional constructor argument:

```
class T1Mapper implements ResultSetMapper<T1Object> {
  public T1Mapper() { this(""); }
  public T1Mapper(String prefix) {
    this.prefix = prefix;
  }

  private final String prefix;

  T1Object map(int i, ResultSet rs, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException {
    return new T1Object(rs.getInt(prefix + "id"),
                        rs.getString(prefix + "name"));
  }
}

// ditto for t2 mapper
```

Thus, when you have situations that require joining multiple tables that have column names in common, label each column in your query to disambiguate them:

```
List<T1Object> handle.createQuery("select t1.id t1_id, t1.name t1_name, " +
                   "t2.id t2_id, t2.name t2_name " +
                   "from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 " +
                   "on t1.id = t2.t1_id")
      .map(new ResultSetMapper<T1Object>() {
        T1Mapper t1Mapper = new T1Mapper("t1_");
        T2Mapper t2Mapper = new T2Mapper("t2_");

        public T1Object map(int i, ResultSet rs, StatementContext ctx) {
          T1Object t1 = t1Mapper.map(i, rs, ctx);
          T2Object t2 = t2Mapper.map(i, rs, ctx);
          t1.setT2Object(t2);
          return t1;
        }
      })
      .list();
```

Unless there's some fancy trick I haven't heard about, there's really no getting around having to prefix your column names like that--unless you want to write a custom join row mapper by hand.

I think we've addressed this use case a lot better in v3 (still in alpha). All the reflective mappers like `BeanMapper` now support a column name prefix, as described above, out of the box. We also added `JoinRowMapper` which makes this stupid simple:

```
@SqlQuery("select t1.id t1_id, t1.name t1_name, " +
          "t2.id t2_id, t2.name t2_name " +
          "from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 " +
          "on t1.id = t2.t1_id")
@RegisterBeanMapper(value = {T1Object.class, T2Object.class},
                    prefix = {"t1_", "t2_"})
@RegisterJoinRowMapper({T1Object.class, T2Object.class})
List<JoinRow> listJoins();
```

Thus:

```
myDao.listJoins()
     .stream()
     .map(joinRow -> {
       T1Object t1 = joinRow.get(T1Object.class);
       T2Object t2 = joinRow.get(T2Object.class);

       // merge the individual entities in your join rows however you like
       t1.setT2(t2);
       return t1;
     })
     .collect(toList());
```